# PHP API workaround for application?

Tags: php, api

I want to use an encoded PHP application which blocks bad traffic to create my own API with it. It only has 2 ways of "return", letting a visitor visit a website or displaying a .html block message to him. How could I query my domain A with the PHP application from domain B, C, D to check if a visitor is bad traffic?

I thought of letting domain A only displaying a '1' as content, so visitors which pass the test will see only this number. Is there a more elegant and faster way then my solution:

```
$url = 'www.protected-domain-A.com';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
if (strpos($content, '1') !== false) {
echo 'Visitor is good, let him pass!';
}
```

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're trying to do here. Do you just want to white/blacklist certain URLs from accessing your site?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a token or user authentication approach.

One way to do that is to use a framework that already has a solution for you.
You could try some:

- lumen/laravel - https://lumen.laravel.com/
- slim framwork - http://www.slimframework.com/
- zend framework - http://framework.zend.com/
- Yii framework - http://www.yiiframework.com/

And a lot more. But if you really want to manually do that, you should search for "php token authentication" or "php oauth2". This is the way mostly people uses nowadays.